# How to read settings of log4net from second config file?

Tags: c#, log4net, app-config

I use log4net in my project. However, I want to read settings of lognet from second config file (log4net.config). How can I do this?

Comment: Please clarify: log4net is already reading from a config file and you want to additionally consider a second config file? Like merging two config files?

Comment: you mean something like this?
http://theburningmonk.com/2010/03/dot-net-tips-using-configsource-or-file-attribute-to-externalize-config-sections/